# Comparing current line to next one using fgets?

Tags: c, file-io, fgets

I'm trying to access the next line using fgets in order to count the number of lines that are similar to the next one, is there anyway to get the nextLine variable?

```css
int similar = 0;
char line[100];
char nextLine[100];
FILE *f = fopen(file, "r");
while (fgets(line, 100, f)) {
            if (strcmp(nextLine, line) == '0') {
                      similar++;
            }
}
```

Comment: Have you though that it is the same as comparing to the *previous* line?

Comment: Don't use all-uppercase names for anything else than macros or enum-constants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible - add a new var `next_line`. For example,

```
int similar = 0;
char line[100] = "";
char next_line[100] = "";

FILE *f = fopen(file, "r");
while (fgets(line, 100, f)) {
    if (strcmp(next_line, line) == 0) {
            similar++;
    }
    strcpy(next_line, line);
}
```

NOTE:

- You must check `strcmp` with `0`, not `'0'`
- This only works to compare adjacent lines.

Comment: If your first line is empty you will get a false positive.

Comment: Wouldn't it be faster just swapping the pointers to the two lines?

Comment: @EugeneSh. that case isn't a false positive - do you remember `fgets` add a newline?

Comment: So what will happen in case of a file with a single newline? It will count 1 if I parse it correctly..

Comment: If the file has a single new line - the `while` loop read just once and assign it to `line` - whereas `next_line` remains empty - so `strcmp` check return non-zero, `similar` is not increased

Answer (score 0):

Compare current line with previous line or compare current line with a defined string:
 
Ex. My textfile contains this text:

`This is a line // (\n)`
`This is a line // (\n)`
`This is a line // without newline`

```
char line_comp []  = "This is a line\n"; // For lines with newline
char line_comp2 [] = "This is a line";   // For lines without newline
char line[255];                          // Store the line
```

Now we can go through the file and see if the lines match one of the above:

```
int equal = 0;
while (fgets(line, 255, f) != NULL) {
    if (strcmp(line, line_comp) == 0 || strcmp(line, line_comp2) == 0)
        ++equal;
}
```

And then finally print the result: `printf("Lines equal: %d\n", equal);` 
Remember to check if the file was opened correctly and remember to close the file after use.